# Is there a word or phrase for "when someone tells you to do something and you're going to do but they continuously tell you to do it"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

There are a lot of people like this. They tell you to do something, you say OK and you're going to do it (in a short time like 10 minutes or so), but if they see that you are not doing immediately what they told you, they will continuously tell you "do it", "do it", "do it". Like, every 10 seconds, they tell you to do it and annoy you so much so you do it.

Is there a word or phrase to express that in English? I only want to know a phrase for *telling again and again continuously*.

Example: My uncle told me to bring him tea while I was reading a book. I was in the middle of a paragraph when he told me that. I told him "OK, bringing". Then I continued reading, just wanted to finish the paragraph, my uncle says again "bring the tea". And he continued to say that after every 10 seconds. I had not finished the paragraph and he said that so many times that he made me stop reading and bring him tea.

Is there a word or phrase for that?

Comment: I've never dealt with an adult who did that. Periodic reminders sure, general nagging, yes, but not every ten seconds until the task is done, not even every couple of minutes. If someone tried that with me they wouldn't get what they wanted.

Comment: Look up PITA, all capital letters, it fits your description :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your uncle was *nagging* you.

> **Nagging:** (of a person) constantly harassing someone to do something.
>
> [[Google dictionary]](https://www.google.com/search?q=nagging)

> nag = to criticize or complain often in an annoying way, especially in order to try and make someone do something
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nag)

Comment: *Nagging* is what this is normally called in more "normal" situations without the every-ten-seconds-till-you-comply factor, which in my opinion pushes it over the line to abnormal harassment.

Comment: @nnnnnn I sympathise with your reservation to some extent but the questioner's emphasis on the repetitive aspect is crucially linked with "complaining in an annoying way" or "constantly harassing", which are key parts of the definitions of *nagging* .

Answer (score 0):

Your uncle *is like a dog with a bone* about getting you to serve tea.

> not willing to stop until you have finished dealing with something, especially a problem that is worrying you
>
> [[Macmillan Dictionary]](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/like-a-dog-with-a-bone)

Comment: To me, *like a dog with a bone* indicates that the subject themselves has an obsession with, usually, a particular point of contention. *"individuals who are called creative are really more like a dog with a bone. They refuse to let go of an idea."* The Man Who Tasted Shapes - Page 89 books.google.co.uk by Richard E. Cytowic

Answer (score 0):

Such a person is **'micromanaging'.**

> : to manage especially with excessive control or attention to details

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/micromanage)

> a management style whereby a manager closely observes and/or controls and/or **reminds the work of his/her subordinates** or employees.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micromanagement#:%7E:text=9%20External%20links-,Definition,excessive%20attention%20to%20minor%20details%22.)

> NYPD Chief of Patrol Abruptly Retires Over Mayor's Micromanaging, Undermining: Sources

[NBC- October 13/2020](https://www.nbcnewyork.com/news/local/nypd-chief-of-patrol-abruptly-retiring-official-says/2666042/)

Comment: *Micromanaging* doesn't apply to the OP's example about the tea.